# Why when I connect an external harddisk via an USB 3.0 PCI controller I receive the "your device can perform faster" notification?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, usb-3

I have an [external HD with usb 3.0 support](http://www.verbatim.com/prod/hard-drives/desktop/usb-3.0-sku-97416/) and have installed a [PCI card](http://english.hamletcom.com/products/husb302pcx.aspx) to add two usb 3.0 ports to my pc. I am running windows 7.

When I connect the hard disk I receive a notification about usb speed: "your device can perform faster" ... 
I have installed the provided drivers (for the so called NEC Electronics USB 3.0 Host controller) and the device is reported to be "properly working". The driver version is 1.0.19.0 and the firmware version is 3025 (as reported by the provided utility).

Is the message reliable? How can I fix it (achieving the usb 3.0 speed obviously :-) )?

Comment: Are you sure that your external hard drive is USB 3.0?

Comment: were you using a USB 3.0 compliant cable?

Comment: Did you check the BIOS ?  Some have Enhanced Controller (EC) options, ensure it is enabled on your machine.

Comment: PCI or PCIe? PCI can't handle USB 3.0's full speed

Comment: Try benchmarking the HDD and tell us what transfer speeds you're getting.  Also, @Luke, the card he linked to above *is* indeed a PCIe USB controller.

Comment: @breakthrough what's the most reliable way to benchmark this? I tried copying from my internal hdd to the external a large number of files (raw photos), and I have set up a counter on PerfMon of bytes written per sec. I get values between 25 and 50M per second.

Comment: @Diogo: that's what Verbatim is saying :) Jokes apart, I am rather sure. Keltari: The connector of the cable and of the ports are blue, I have no reason to suspect a forgery.

Comment: @Breakthrough I was on my iPhone so I usually don't click links. But good to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the thread [USB 3.0 bracket Low 2.0 Speeds](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2140955) the problem was electrical interference.
I suppose that at USB 3 speeds everything must be perfect.
The thread mentions "ferrite core **IN** the bracket connector", which is unfamiliar to me.
Does your cable have a [ferrite bead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) ?
(I would maybe try a better-quality cable.)

EDIT

The blog [“This Device Can Perform Faster” USB 3.0 Pop-up](http://blog.premiumusb.com/2011/07/usb-3-device-questions-fixes/) lists all the possibilities :

1. Temperamental connections and devices
   Try disconnecting and reconnecting.  Since USB 3.0 uses additional contacts, it’s important to achieve a tight connection
2. Drivers
   CNET offers an excellent resource for [free drivers](http://download.cnet.com/windows/usb-drivers/).
3. Overclocking
   The DRAM for the motherboard that you set to a certain frequency for performance may be incompatible with your port or USB 3.0 card because it affects the PCI bus.  By reducing the speed of your front side bus (FSB), 3.0 can operate as intended.
   See also [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/259843-14-device-perform-faster), where down-tuning the FSB off by 20MHz made it start working.

Comment: That was for a connector that was extended to a bracket with interference being picked up by the extension inside the case. His connectors are not extended and there's no reason he should have this particular problem.

Comment: @Francesco: I added some more possibilities.

Comment: Since I removed and replugged the cable for taking the [photo](http://superuser.com/questions/326478/why-when-i-connect-an-external-harddisk-via-an-usb-3-0-pci-controller-i-receive-t/328099#328099) I have not receveid the message again. It appears that the cable was not well plugged but worked properly nonetheless (although not achieving usb 3 speed). I was sure to have cheked it but.. that's what happened. Not believing to what I was seeing, I have tried plugging the cable in an USB 2.0 port and the message popped up again, so it's not that i turned off notification. Never seen such a thing.

Comment: All is well that ends well. Just to remark that accepting the answer and awarding the bounty are separate actions.

Comment: @Francesco I have seen the same thing happen to me. It appears that it reverts to USB2.0 speeds if the connection isn't just right. Perhaps USB 2.0 is more tolerant of noise in the signal than USB 3.0 is.

Comment: @harrymc really? I thought that if the OP doesn't accept any answer the most upvoted gets the bounty, and if the OP accepts an answer the bounty is awarded to the answerer. Let me check the rules...

Comment: @sidran32 thanks for the reassuring information. I was already beginning to think of having to set up a search for some elusive hardware failure...

Comment: @Francesco: There is a complex system of rules for unawarded bounties. Most of the rules are in the FAQ, but not all.

Comment: @harrymc I refreshed my memory and awarded the bounty :-)

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that you connected two USB 3.0 devices to each other with a USB 2.0 cable. You need a SuperSpeed cable that has the extra 4 connectors.

http://www.everythingusb.com/speed.html#2

Comment: it is interesting that both you and @harrymc thought about the cable. I am using the one which was provided by Verbatim. It reports usb 3.0 on it, I shot a [photo](http://i.imgur.com/DYTVJ.jpg) of it. The brand is [BizLink](http://www.bizlinktech.com/usb3.html).

Comment: That is a USB 3.0 cable. Unless it's damaged, it should give you USB 3.0 speeds.